# Algebraic K-theory of complex varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Maybe this question is trivial, but I was not able to find an answer. The question is this: Consider the algebraic K-theory of smooth complex projective varieties (such that the K-theory and the G-theory agree). Does it have the Mayer-Vietoris property for the analytic topology? I know it does for the Zarisky topology. If the answer is negative is it possible to have an example?

### Update

In view of the comments I felt the need to elaborate my question. Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety. Let $G(X)$ be the $K-$theory space of the category of coherent sheaves over $X$. If $U$ and $V$ are two Zariski open subschemes one has the following homotopy cartesian square:$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G(U \cup V) @>>> G(U)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
G(V) @>>> G(U \cap V)
\end{CD}

Does it remain true if $U$ and $V$ are open subsets in the usual (complex) topology of $X$?

Here an open subset $U$ is seen as a ringed space with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X|_U$.

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense -- if I take an analytic but not algebraic open set, what is its algebraic K-theory supposed to be?

Comment: I think that by GAGA an analytic subset will be also algebraic.

Comment: @AndreiHalanay I usually understand "analytic topology" to mean the classical topology where we consider $X$ as a real manifold. So, if $X = \mathbb{C}$ with the standard algebraic structure, then the open disc of radius $1$ is open for the analytic topology, but doesn't come with an algebraic structure. If I am confused, could you spell out your definitions?

Comment: I see you edited your question to say that you are thinking about projective varieties, but an open subset of a projective variety is almost never projective. So any interesting example of Mayer-Vietores takes you out of the projective world (or else I am confused.)

Comment: @David Speyer Sorry, I was asking about projective varieties, but somehow the word was left out. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I would be doubtful of the thesis, since algebraic K-theory does not satisfy *étale* descent, which should be weaker than descent for the analytic topology.

Comment: In your comment to Alan, you write "by GAGA, an analytic subset of $X$ will be algebraic." If $X$ is an algebraic complex manifold, there are THREE topologies on $X$: (1) The topology where we consider $X$ as an ordinary real manifold, usually called the analytic topology (2) What I've sometimes heard called the "analytic Zariski topology", where closed sets must locally be zeroes of analytic functions (3) The Zariski topology, sometimes called "algebraic Zariski topology" for emphasis, where closed sets are locally zeroes of algebraic functions.

Comment: See Defn 5.8 in http://www.massey.math.neu.edu/Massey/Massey_preprints/sing_notes.pdf for a source that uses these terms in this way.

Comment: As I (and I think most people) use terminology, "analytic subset" means "closed in topology (2)". GAGA (or rather, Chow's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry#Chow.27s_theorem ) states that (2) and (3) agree for projective varieties. I think this might be the source of the confusion.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I was thinking about the complex topology as defined in Neeman's book *Algebraic and Analytic Geometry* Chap. 4 (seems like (1)-the topology induced by the embedding in $\mathbb{P}^n$).

Comment: @DenisNardin Indeed the étale and complex topologies are in some sense equivalent (this is Th. 21. 2 from [Milne's Lectures on Etale Cohomology](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LEC.pdf). But K-theory satisfies Mayer-Vietoris for the Nisnevich topology which is finer than the Zariski one and it is not clear to me the relationship between Nisnevich and complex topologies.

Comment: @Andrei You could try to look at the proof of the localization theorem in Thomason-Trobaugh and see if it carries through in the analytic setting. I cannot think of any obvious obstruction, so that's at least a positive sign. The proof is fairly complicated though, so maybe it isn't worth it.

Comment: It seems that you have attracted experts much more knowledgeable than I am, but I am still curious: If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^1$, for example, $\{ (x:y) : |x| < |y| \}$, what is the algebraic $K$-theory of $U$?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I assume $U$ to be also a variety.

Comment: But then isn't this just asking the question in the Zariski topology?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer You're right. Once again it's clear that the analytic topology is not good for algebraic geometry. I am interested in fact by complex manifolds, but given that a similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199210/k-theory-of-coherent-sheaves-on-complex-manifolds-references-and-gamma-filtrati was left answered I was hoping that in a more "algebraic" setting there was some work done.